# Can a threaded rod in my foundation wall (in both wall anchors and support beams) that is leaking be made water tight?

Tags: foundation

Work was done on our foundation walls in 2003. We bought the house in 2016 and are now experiencing water leaking at the threaded rods coming in our house in both wall anchor plates and support beams. Work has been done on all points already and there is still water coming in those spots at the threaded rods.  Will a drain tile system with a vapor barrier be a good enough solution?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Describe where your plate-foundation joint is relative to grade. Please also describe (maybe with a drawing) the 'threaded rods and support beams.

Comment: What “work has been done on all points already”? A picture would help...I’ve got to see water coming out around the “threaded rods”.

Comment: Is your property laid out so any parts of the property are at a lower elevation than your basement floor?